# How to limit no of comments in a page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating feedback page in wordpress application. I am using

```
 <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

code in my template file. I don't know how should I limit no. of comments in a page.
Basically I want that it should display 4 comments in the feedback page. After 4 comments there should be pagination of comments. Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the admin panel-

Settings > Discussion > Other comment settings > Tick - Break comments into pages with [NUMBER] ......