# WordPress Comments: How to show the limited number of replies of comments?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site with many comments. each comment shows all their reply, so the page is very long to scroll.

```
- Post
  -- Comment #1
     -- Reply 1
     -- Reply 2
     -- Reply 3
     -- Reply 4
     -- Reply 5
     -- Reply 6
     -- Reply 7
     -- Reply 8
  -- Comment #2
     -- Reply 1
     -- Reply 2
     -- Reply 3
     -- Reply 4
     -- Reply 5
     -- Reply 6
     -- Reply 7
  -- Comment #3
  -- NN..
```

How to show only 5 last reply each comment like this:

```
- Post
  -- Comment #1
     -- Reply 4
     -- Reply 5
     -- Reply 6
     -- Reply 7
     -- Reply 8
  -- Comment #2
     -- Reply 3
     -- Reply 4
     -- Reply 5
     -- Reply 6
     -- Reply 7
  -- Comment #3
  -- NN..
```

I explored WordPress `comment query`, but didn't find any filter (eg: `pre_comment_query`, `the_comments`) to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit no of comments in a page in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473762/how-to-limit-no-of-comments-in-a-page-in-wordpress)

Comment: As you already know, WordPress will list all comments and their replies by default. If you want a different behavior you'll have to roll up your own solution.

Comment: @connectyourcharger the default settings only work for parent comment, not affected to child comment. Ex the setting say 5 comments, the reply keep show all comments.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress:
Settings / Discussion / See the relevant settings here.

Via code (untested):

```
add_filter('thread_comments_depth_max', function($max){return 5;});
```

Source: https://wpza.net/increase-the-nested-comments-level/

Comment: Sorry sir, but the code not working. Not the depth length but limit the reply for each comment.